# Driver to split audio to 2 different devices?

Tags: windows, audio

I recently bought one of these USB headsets against my own better judgement, and it's really costing my sanity at this point.  Previously when using a standard jack, I just used a splitter so I could split off the things I was doing with my TV or headset, I could just turn the TV off or the headset volume down should I want to use one at a time.

Now, along comes this USB headset and I find that I can't choose for the sound of 1 application to pipe to 2 different devices on Windows; How can I solve this?  Does any software out there exist for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Windows processes sound through either one device or the other. My experience is that if you need usb sound for some reason, you're better off with [something like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000N35A0Y) that let's you plug in anything you want (including a splitter, and at <$4 the price is right, too).

Comment: Yeah, I didn't *need* USB sound.  It's just that pretty much the only thing available in Wal-mart now are these USB headphones.  I really didn't have a choice unless I wanted to order my headset online and wait a week for delivery (not feasible because I had some business that REQUIRED me to have a headset NOW.)